# An alternative to PIMPL Idiom when you'd like the interface to have all the memory

Tags: c++

The purpose of the PIMPL idiom is to hide implementation, including methods, structures, and even sizes of structures. One downside is it uses the heap.

However, what if I didn't want to hide the size requirements of anything. I just wanted to hide methods, the formatting of the structure and the variable names. One way would be to allocate an array of bytes of the perfect size, have the implementation constantly cast that to whatever structure and use that. But manually find the size of the bytes to allocate for the object? And do casts all the time? Obviously not practical.

Is there an idiom or general way of handling this case that is advantageous to PIMPL or opaque pointers.

Comment: I am not sure why using the heap is a downside? What I think you are suggesting sounds rather predisposed to bugginess and very hard to maintain. I suppose some kind of factory would manage the casting but managing the internal padding is very compiler/compiler-version/compiler-flag specific.

Comment: You might be interested in the [Fast Pimpl](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/028.htm).

Comment: In C++ there is no good solution for this problem (only hacks), PIMPL also has its downside: casting void pointers. C++ header files are often messy and the public interface is lost among private member declarations. C#'s partial classes solve this problem elegantly but even that thing has its downsides.

Comment: @Galik: using the heap can add a large cost in terms of performance and memory fragmentation in applications where there are a very number of objects -- I have experienced this problem with some Pimpl classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A rather different approach could be to rethink the nature of what your objects really represent.  In traditional OOP it's customary to think of all objects as self-contained entities that have their own data and methods.  Some of those methods will be private to the class because they're just required for that class's own housekeeping, and so these are the kind of thing you usually move the 'impl' of a Pimpl class.

In a recent project I've been favouring the [Domain-Driven Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321125215) approach where one of the desirables is to separate the data from the logic that does things with it. The data classes then become little more than structs, and the complex logic that previously was hidden in the Pimpl now can go in a Service object that has no state of its own.

Consider a (rather contrived) example of a game loop:

```
class EnemySoldier : public GameObject
{
public:
    // just implement the basic GameObject interface
    void        updateState();
    void        draw(Surface&);

private:
    std::unique_ptr<EnemySoldierImp>  m_Pimpl;
};
```

```
class EnemySolderImpl
{
public:
      // 100 methods of complex AI logic
      // that you don't want exposed to clients

private:
    StateData       m_StateData;
};
```

```
void runGame()
{
    for (auto gameObject : allGameObjects) {
        gameObject->updateState();
    }
}
```

This could be restructured so that instead of the `GameObjects` managing their data *and* their program logic, we separate these two things out:

```
class EnemySoldierData
{
public:
    // some getters may be allowed, all other data only 
    // modifiable by the Service class. No program logic in this class
private:
    friend class EnemySoldierAIService;
    StateData       m_StateData;
};
```

```
class EnemySoldierAIService
{
public:
    EnemySoldierAIService() {}

    void updateState(Game& game) {
        for (auto& enemySoldierData : game.getAllEnemySoldierData()) {
            updateStateForSoldier(game, enemySoldierData);
        }
    }

    // 100 methods of AI logic are now here

    // no state variables
};
```

We now don't have any need for Pimpls or any hacky tricks with memory allocation. We can also use the game programming technique of getting better cache performance and reduced memory fragmentation by storing the global state in several flat vectors rather than needing an array of pointers-to-base-classes, eg:

```
class Game
{
public:
        std::vector<EnemySoldierData> m_SoldierData;
        std::vector<MissileData>     m_MissileData;
        ...
}
```

I find that this general approach really simplifies a lot of program code:

- There's less need for Pimpls
- The program logic is all in one place
- It's much easier to retain backwards compatibility or drop in alternate implementations by choosing between the V1 and V2 version of the Service class at runtime
- Much less heap allocation

Comment: Your design pattern is nice but do not provide the same type of services PIMPL is designed for, namely the fact that you will have those 100 methods of AI logic in your public headers so that if you want to make a change in the implementation you  will, at the very least, force recompilation in the client

Comment: for me DDD and pimp are solutions of completely different problems of different scales. pimpl is more like hide stuff from class user to maintain binary compatibility (what is important for public libraries). On other hand DDD is more about software architecture. So both things address completely different issues.

Answer (score 2):

The information you are trying to hide is exactly the same information the compiler needs in order to calculate the size.  Which is to say, no, there is no idiom for finding the size without knowing the number and data types of the non-static members, because it isn't even possible.

On the other hand, you can hide the existence of helper functions just fine.  Simply declare a nested type (this gives the nested members access to the private members of the outer class) and define that type only inside your private implementation file, putting your helper logic in static member functions of the nested type.  You'll have to pass a pointer to the object instance to operate on as a parameter, but then you can access all members.

Example:

```
class FlatAPI
{
    void helperNeedsPublicAccess();
    void helperNeedsFullAccess();

    T data;
public:
    void publicFunction();
};
```

becomes

```
class PublicAPI
{
    struct helpers;

    T data;
public:
    void publicFunction();
};
```

and implementation code

```
#include <public.h>

static void helperNeedsPublicAccess(PublicAPI* pThis) { pThis->publicFunction(); }

struct PublicAPI::helpers
{
    static void helperNeedsFullAccess(PublicAPI* pThis) { std::cout << pThis->data; }
};

void PublicAPI::publicFunction()
{
    helpers::helperNeedsFullAccess(this);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So here's a possible alternative that doesn't have the downsides of constant casting but improves the memory layout to make it similar to if you hadn't used PIMPL at all.

I'm going to assume that you application isn't really using just one pimpl, but actually you are using the pimpl for many classes, so its like, the impl of the first pimpl holds pimpls for many children classes, and the impls of those hold pimpls to many third-tier classes etc.

(The kinds of objects I'm envisioning are like, all the managers, the schedulers, the various kinds of engines in your app. Most likely not all the actual data records, those are probably in a standard container owned by one of the managers. But all the objects that you generally only have a fixed number of in the course of the application.)

The first idea is, similar to how `std::make_shared` works, I want to allocate the main object right along-side the "helper" object so that I get the "fast" memory layout without breaking encapsulation. The way I do this is allocate a contiguous block of memory big enough for both, and use placement new, so that the pimpl is right next to the impl.

By itself, that's not really any improvement, because the pimpl is just the size of a pointer, and whoever owns the pimpl now needs a pointer to the pimpl since it's now heap allocated.

However, now we basically try to do this for all of the layers at once.

What is needed to actually make this work:

- Each pimpl class needs to expose a static member function which is available *at run time* which indicates its size in bytes. If the corresponding impl is simple, this might just be `return sizeof(my_impl)`. If the corresponding impl contains other pimpls, then this is `return sizeof(my_impl) + child_pimpl1::size() + child_pimpl2::size() + ...`.
- Each pimpl class needs a custom `operator new` or similar factory function that will allocate to a given block of memory of the appropriate size

  - The pimpl and its impl (minus the pimpl children you are handling recursively)
  - Each of the pimpl children in succession, using their corresponding `operator new` or similar function.

Now, at the beginning of your app, you make one gigantic heap allocation which holds the "root" manager object or whatever corresponding object. (If there isn't one then you would introduce one just for this purpose.) And you use its factory function there, allocating all of these objects contiguously.

I think this gives essentially the same benefits as if you made all the pimpls hold `char[]` of the exactly right size and constantly casted things. It will only work well though if you really only need a fixed number of these guys, or never too many. If you need to tear down and rebuild these objects often, that's okay, since you'll just manually call the destructors and use placement new to reconstruct. But you won't really be able to give any of the memory back until the end of the application, so there's some trade-off involved.

Answer (score -1):

> The purpose of the PIMPL idiom is to hide implementation, including
>   methods, structures, and even sizes of structures.

See also, http://herbsutter.com/gotw/_100/

> One downside is it uses the heap.

I consider the use of the heap an upside.  Stack is much more valuable and
much more limited (8Mbytes vs 3GBytes on my hw).

> However, what if I didn't want to hide the size requirements of
>   anything.

My imagination has failed me many times.  I will try to assume you know
what you want, and why you want it.

IMHO, failing to hide size info is of no consequence.

> I just wanted to hide methods, and the formatting of the structure and
>   the variable names.

I think you still need to expose ctor and dtor
(or named alternatives i.e. createFoo/removeFoo )

> One way would be to allocate an array of bytes of the perfect size,

this is easily done.

> have the implementation constantly cast that to whatever structure and
>   use that.

IMHO no casting is required (I have never needed it - see MCVE below.)

But, even if you cast for some reason I can't guess at,
remember that casting (without conversion) causes no code,
and thus no performance issue.

> But manually find the size of the bytes to allocate for the object?

Pragmatically this is only a minor challenge during development
(when the size might change).  In my earlier career, I have
initially guessed for a dozen efforts, typically using a somewhat bigger than necessary data size estimate to accommodate growth.

I then add a run time assert (you might prefer to use "if clause")
to generate notices when the size is bigger than the goal.  It has been my experience that the data size has always stabilized very quickly.

It is trivial to make the size info exact (if you want).

> And do casts all the time? Obviously not practical.

I do not understand why you think casts are involved. I do not use
any in the pimples I create (nor in the MCVE below).

I do not understand why you (and at least 1 other) think casts are not
practical.  non-conversion casts cost nothing (at runtime) and are
completely handled by the compiler. Maybe I will ask SO some related question someday.  Even my editor can automate the cast prefix.

I do not understand why at least 1 comment thinks there are void
pointers to cast.  I have used none.

> Is there an idiom or general way of handling this case that is
>   advantageous to PIMPL or opaque pointers.

I know of no such idiom.  I have found several examples that I think
conform to my expectations of handling pimpl, does that make them
general?  Probably not.

Note, however, that from my many years in embedded systems work I
consider the below listed summarized ideas / requirements as relatively simple
challenges.

Feed back welcome.

---

Summary Requirements:

1. cancel size information hiding.  Size info exposure is acceptable.
2. hide methods (exception: ctor and dtor or named ctor/dtor alternatives)
3. allocate array of bytes (implBuff) as location for pimple attribute.

   - manually provide pimple size info
4. provide output to cout the current impl size (to simplify development)

   - assert when manual size of implBuff is too small to hold actual impl
   - assert when manual size of implBuff is too wasteful of space

demonstrate why casting is not required
    (hmmm, negative proofs are difficult.how about I simply show code with no casting needed)

5. Make note of pathological dependencies, show pragmatic solution if easy

---

NOTE:

These choices are sometimes not without 'pathological dependencies',
I have found 2, which I think are easily handled or ignored.  See below.

---

The following MCVE builds and runs on my Ubuntu 15.04, g++ ver 4.9.2-10ubuntu13

An example output follows the code:

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>

  // ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // file Foo.hh
  class Foo     // a pimple example
  {
  public:
     Foo();
     ~Foo();

     // alternative for above two methods: use named ctor/dtor

     // diagnostics only
     std::string show();

     // OTHER METHODS not desired

  private:
     // pathological dependency 1 - manual guess vs actual size
     enum SizeGuessEnum { SizeGuess = 24048 };

     char implBuff [SizeGuess]; // space inside Foo object to hold FooImpl
     // NOTE - this is _not_ an allocation - it is _not_ new'd, so do not delete

     // optional: declare the name of the class/struct to hold Foo attributes
     //   this is only a class declaration, with no implementation info
     //   and gives nothing away with its name
     class FooImpl;

     // USE RAW pointer only, DO NOT USE any form of unique_ptr
     // because pi does _not_ point to a heap allocated buffer
     FooImpl*   pi;  // pointer-to-implementation
  };





  // ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // top of file Foo.cc

  typedef std::vector<std::string> StringVec;


  // the impl defined first
  class Foo::FooImpl
  {
  private:
     friend class Foo;  // allow Foo full access

     FooImpl() : m_indx(++M_indx)
        {
           std::cout << "\n   Foo::FooImpl() sizeof() = "
                     << sizeof(*this); // proof this is accessed
        }

     ~FooImpl()  { m_indx = 0; }


     uint64_t  m_indx;  // unique id for this instance

     StringVec m_stringVec[1000]; // room for 1000 strings

     static uint64_t M_indx;
  };

  uint64_t Foo::FooImpl::M_indx = 0;  // allocation of static



  // Foo ctor
  Foo::Foo(void) : pi (nullptr)
  {
     // pathological dependency 1 - manual guess vs actual size
     {
        // perform a one-time run-time VALIDATE of SizeGuess

        // get the compiler's actual size
        const size_t ActualSize = sizeof(FooImpl);

        // SizeGuess must accomodate entire FooImpl
        assert(SizeGuess >= ActualSize);

        // tolerate some extra buffer - production code might combine above with below to make exact
        // SizeGuess can be a little bit too big, but not more than 10 bytes too big
        assert(SizeGuess <= (ActualSize+10));
     }

     // when get here, the implBuff has enough space to hold a complete  Foo::FooImpl

     // some might say that the following 'for loop' would cause undefined behavior
     // by treating the code differently than subsequent usage
     // I think it does not matter, so I will skip
     {
        // 0 out the implBuff
        // for (int i=0; i<SizeGuess; ++i) implBuff[i] = 0;
     }

     // pathological dependency 2 - use of placement new
     //   --> DOES NOT allocate heap space  (so do not deallocate in dtor)
     pi = new (implBuff) FooImpl();

     // NOTE: placement new does not allocate, it only runs the ctor at the address
     //       confirmed by cout of m_indx
  }

  Foo::~Foo(void)
  {
     // pathological dependency 2 - placement new DOES NOT allocate heap space
     // DO NOT delete what pi points to


     // YOU MAY perform here the actions you think are needed of the FooImpl dtor
     // or
     // YOU MAY write a FooImpl.dtor and directly invoke it (i.e. pi->~FooImpl() )
     //
     // BUT -- DO NOT delete pi, because FOO did not allocate *pi
  }


  std::string Foo::show() // for diagnostics only
  {
     // because foo is friend class, foo methods have direct access to impl
     std::stringstream ss;
     ss << "\nsizeof(FooImpl): " << sizeof(FooImpl)
        << "\n      SizeGuess: " << SizeGuess
        << "\n           this: " << (void*) this
        << "\n      &implBuff: " << &implBuff
        << "\n     pi->m_indx: " << pi->m_indx;
     return (ss.str());
  }


int t238(void) // called by main
{
   {
      Foo foo;
      std::cout << "\n   foo on stack: " << sizeof(foo) << " bytes";
      std::cout <<  foo.show() << std::endl;
   }

   {
      Foo* foo = new Foo;

      std::cout << "\nfoo ptr to Heap: " << sizeof(foo) << " bytes";
      std::cout << "\n    foo in Heap: " << sizeof(*foo) << " bytes";
      std::cout <<  foo->show() << std::endl;

      delete foo;
   }

   return (0);
}
```

---

Example output:

```
// output
//    Foo::FooImpl() sizeof() = 24008
//    foo on stack: 24056 bytes
// sizeof(FooImpl): 24008
//       SizeGuess: 24048
//            this: 0x7fff269e37d0
//       &implBuff: 0x7fff269e37d0
//      pi->m_indx: 1
//
//    Foo::FooImpl() sizeof() = 24008
// foo ptr to Heap: 8 bytes
//     foo in Heap: 24056 bytes
// sizeof(FooImpl): 24008
//       SizeGuess: 24048
//            this: 0x1deffe0
//       &implBuff: 0x1deffe0
//      pi->m_indx: 2
```

Comment: You can surely lift the validation of the guessed size to take place at compile time... but actually adjusting the constant value remains a maintenance burden.

Comment: example: `switch (0) { case 0: case (GuessedSize >= sizeof(FooImpl): case 2*(GuessedSize <= sizeof(FooImpl) + 10): break; };`